# Как определить территориальную принадлежность при геокодировании

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Допустим, есть такой запрос к геокодеру:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=Салтыковский%20лесопарк
```

Адрес запроса: "Салтыковский Лесопарк". Но в ответе геокодера нет информации, что этот лесопарк относится к Балашихе, или к Московской Области. Как можно определить, к чему он относится, кроме как к России?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо обратно геокодировать полученные координаты лесопарка, с нужным параметром kind, например, locality:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=37.901979,55.732408&kind=locality
```